# Binary file uploaded via postman is corrupted in my flask application

Tags: python, flask, postman, zip

When I upload a zip file to my flask app using postman (Body ==> binary), and trying to unzip it, my application says the zip file is corrupted.

logs :

```
error [/tmp/be0fc947f7bc4f63a71e7f35af5210e2.zip]: missing 3183380268 bytes in zipfile

2021-03-24T01:20:57.515+01:00   (attempting to process anyway)

2021-03-24T01:20:57.515+01:00   error [/tmp/be0fc947f7bc4f63a71e7f35af5210e2.zip]: start of central directory not found;

2021-03-24T01:20:57.515+01:00   zipfile corrupt.

2021-03-24T01:20:57.515+01:00   (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the

2021-03-24T01:20:57.515+01:00   appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

flask app :

```
with open("/tmp/myfile.zip", "wb") as binary_file: 
        binary_file.write(request.data)
```

EDIT : also tried to extract with `zipfile`

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/myfile.zip', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall(fil_dir)
```

and got the following error :

`raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for central directory")`

Originally I was extracting with

`os.system("unzip -qq %s -d %s" % (file_path,file_dir))`

Comment: Is the zipfile actually binary?

Comment: @llamaking136 the zipfile is a binary . This is a compressed folder. Not a text file.